Sum of class numbers
Let $p\equiv 3 \text{ mod }4$ be a prime. Consider the sum
$$ h(-4p)+h(-p)$$
where $h$ denotes the class number. To be precise, $h(-p)$ is the order of the class group of $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, and $h(-4p)$ is the order of the class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ (also considered as subring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$). I refer to this question from me.
Now it is claimed in Proposition 2.5 of this (highly influencial) paper (regarding isogeny-based cryptography), that
\begin{align*}
h(-4p)+h(-p)=
\begin{cases}
2h(-p) \text{ if } p\equiv 7\text{ mod }8\\
4h(-p) \text{ if } p\equiv 3\text{ mod }8.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the claim is implicitly that in the first case $h(-4p)=h(-p)$, and in the second case, $h(-4p)=3h(-p)$. Can anyone provide a reference or explanation regarding this claim?
Some ideas:
I am not sure about where the mod $8$ condition arises from. The only thing I can think about is whether the prime $2$ is ramified or splits in the corrsponding numberfield. Therefore, it is evident that we should investigate the splitting behavior of primes in this numberfield. Also, I would expect to possibly learn something about the class group by investigating the splitting behavior of their ideals:
Indeed, for $p\equiv7 \text{ mod }8$, we know that $2$ splits over $\mathcal{O}_K$ into
$$ 2\mathcal{O}_K = \Big(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-p}}{2}\Big)\Big(2,\frac{1-\sqrt{-p}}{2}\Big),$$
p itself is obviously ramified in the form $p\mathcal{O}_K=(\sqrt{-p})^2$, and all other primes $q$ split iff $-p$ is a quadratic residue mod $q$ and are inert otherwise.
An analog analysis can be easily done for $p\equiv 3\text{ mod }8$.
In order to show that $h(-4p)=h(-p)$ for $p\equiv 7\text{ mod }8$, I would hope that the primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ behave analogously. However, all theorems regarding this behavior only consider the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_K$, which sometimes coincides with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$, but in this case does not. How much of this theory is applicable in this szenario?
Indeed, (numerically) it seems like that $2$ does indeed split in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$, as I was able to compute solutions for $x^2-py^2=2$ for the first 30 primes of this form. However, the solutions do not follow such a nice pattern. Further, it is clear that $p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ is again ramified. So far, this supports the assumption that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$ exibits similar behavior like $\mathcal{O}_K$ regarding the splitting of ideals.
However, it is neither clear whether they behavior might even be equal, nor if this would actually be sufficient in order to proof $h(-4p)=h(-p)$.
Besides that, the case of $p\equiv 3\text{ mod }8$ is still completely open. Assigning chatgpt with this problem did just result in the remark that genus theory might be involved in this problem. However, I have no background in this area and some quick survey on this topic did not give me any insights.
I would highly appreciate any hints on literature regarding this problem. As the paper cited above does not lose any word about their claim, it should be some kind of common knowledge in this area of research, however, this is totally unclear for me.
Edit: Further research had led me to this paper which precisely considers the class number for primes congruent $3\text{ mod }8$. However, I do not recognize any application regarding my problem, in particular as $h(-4p)$ is not considered anywhere, and as I do not have sufficient background in order to derive own results upon that.

This is done in detaqil in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. I was looking it up for your last question. The overall thing involved is that the form class group maps to the narrow class group in the imaginary quadratic field. There are recent books that develop forms and ideals side by side; one is Lehman, Quadratic Number Theory. Another is Trifkovic, Algebraic Theory of Quadratic Numbers.

Anyway, the exact thing you ask about is Buell, page 118, Theorem 7.5. I don't have an image, I can type it in an answer

Let's see, for the blog I wrote, the reference was Cohen, A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory. Chapter 5 is Algorithms for Quadratic Fields. The bijection is especially discussed on pages 223-230.

Actually, I came up with an answer myself which I will post hier in case anyone else will encounter the same problem in future:
The result which is applicable here is Corollary 7.28 of the every now and then cited Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ from Cox.

Let $D\equiv 0,1\text{ mod }4$ be negative, and let $m$ be a positive integer. Then
$$ h(m^2D)=\frac{h(D)m}{[\mathcal{O}^*:\mathcal{O}'^*]}\prod\limits_{q\mid m}\Big(1-\Big(\frac{D}{q}\Big)\frac{1}{q}\Big),$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$ are orders of discriminant $D$ and $m^2D$, respectively (and $\mathcal{O}'$ has index $m$ in $\mathcal{O}$).

I changed notation to stay with the variable names in my question. Further, note that $\Big(\frac{D}{q}\Big)$ denotes the Legendre symbol.
We can now use this theorem for both of our cases, that is for arbitrary $D=-p\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$. Further, we have $m=2$ which means that the only factor in the product is $q=2$, and we chose $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathcal{O}'=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$. Notice that the index here is indeed $2$, as required. Further, recall that for imaginary quadratic fields, the unit group is finite, and in our case only consists of $\pm1$. In particular, both the unit group of both orders are equal, thus $[\mathcal{O}^*:\mathcal{O}'^*]$.
Now let us first consider $p\equiv 7\text{ mod }8$. Then $\Big(\frac{D}{q}\Big)=1$ and therefore we obtain
$$ h(-4p) = \frac{2h(-p)}{1}\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2}) = h(-p),$$
as required.
Further, for $p\equiv 3\text{ mod }8$, we have $\Big(\frac{D}{q}\Big)=-1$, thus
$$ h(-4p)=\frac{2h(-p)}{1}\cdot (1+\frac{1}{2})= 3h(-p).$$
This completely answers my question. However, I want to mention that this corollary is NOT proved in this book, as it is only refered to Gauss's Disquisitiones.

I take it back, Buell  has been scanned https://archive.org/details/binaryquadraticf0000buel

But this preview seems to be limited. Can not see all pages and in particular not the one regarding the result.

I've had good luck   with this "Internet Archive."  I managed to make an account. If I call up a book  I  can "borrow"  it on that screen, in particular  there are two or three pages I am placing in an answer. Oh, part of the story is this http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/BLOG_2014_July_15.pdf

Alright, Cox, Theorem 7.7  relates the ideal class group and the form class group.

I am confused by your claim that this corollary isn't proved in Cox's book. Does the corollary not follow from Theorem 7.24, perhaps with a few details left to fill in? I understood the reference to Gauss's book to be historical. In any case, can't you directly apply Theorem 7.24 to your question?

Next morning, guess I should throw in some examples of binary quadratic forms  and the form class number. To save typing, I will use the notation $<a,b,c>$  to refer to the binary quadratic form
$$  f(x,y)  = a x^2 + bxy + c y^2   $$
As you are interested in positive forms, I need show only one Gauss reduced form to represent a class.
For prime $7,$  all  the forms of discriminant $-7$  are
$$   -7 : \hspace{5mm}   < 1, 1, 2>  $$
Then $4 \cdot 7 = 28 $ and
$$   -28 : \hspace{5mm}   < 1, 0, 7>  $$
For prime $23 $  we find
$$      -23:  \hspace{5mm}  < 1, 1, 6>    \hspace{5mm}    -23:  < 2, -1, 3>    \hspace{5mm}    -23:  < 2, 1, 3>  $$   and then
$$      -92:  \hspace{5mm}  < 1, 0, 23>    \hspace{5mm}    -92:  < 3, -2, 8>    \hspace{5mm}    -92:  < 3, 2, 8>  $$
=========================================================
That was $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$  Here comes  $p \equiv 3 \pmod 8$   with the detail that $p > 4.$  In Buell page 118, he says let $X_1^2 + p Y_1^2 = 4$  be the fundamental solution. When $p > 4$   this means $X_1=2,$ then $Y_1=0$  so $Y_1$  is even.   So
For prime $11,$  all  the forms of discriminant $-11$  are
$$   -11 : \hspace{5mm}   < 1, 1, 3>  $$
$$      -44:  \hspace{5mm}  < 1, 0, 11>    \hspace{5mm}    -44:  < 3, -2, 4>     \hspace{5mm}  -44:  < 3, 2, 4>     $$
For $p = 19$
$$   -19 : \hspace{5mm}   < 1, 1, 5>  $$
$$      -76:  \hspace{5mm}  < 1, 0, 19>    \hspace{5mm}    -76:  < 4, -2, 5>     \hspace{5mm}  -76:  < 4, 2, 5>     $$
For $p=131$
$$      -131:  \hspace{5mm}  < 1, 1, 33>    \hspace{5mm}    -131:  < 3, -1, 11>     \hspace{5mm}  -131:  < 3, 1, 11> 
\hspace{5mm}    -131:  < 5, -3, 7>     \hspace{5mm}  -131:  < 5, 3, 7>    $$
I'll get to 524 in a few minutes.  15 classes.
$$      -524:  \hspace{5mm}    < 1, 0, 131>     \hspace{5mm}    -524:    < 3, -2, 44>     \hspace{5mm}  -524:   < 3, 2, 44> 
 \hspace{5mm}    -524:     < 4, -2, 33>     \hspace{5mm}  -524:  < 4, 2, 33> 
\hspace{5mm}    -524:    < 5, -4, 27>      \hspace{5mm}  -524:  < 5, 4, 27>      
      -524:  \hspace{5mm}   < 7, -6, 20>    \hspace{5mm}    -524:   < 7, 6, 20>     \hspace{5mm}  -524:   < 9, -4, 15>  
\hspace{5mm}    -524:   < 9, 4, 15>     \hspace{5mm}  -524:    < 11, -2, 12>   \hspace{5mm}  
      -524:  \hspace{5mm}    < 11, 2, 12>     \hspace{5mm}    -524:  < 12, -10, 13>     \hspace{5mm}  -524: < 12, 10, 13>
\hspace{5mm}    -524:  < 5, -3, 7>     \hspace{5mm}  -524:  < 5, 3, 7>    $$
================================================
From Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms



